# How can I use code to export a SharePoint list to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I found a previous question and it looks to be what I'm looking for. However when I run the code, I get a debug error (Highlights the last line from `"Set ObjMyList . . . . ("A1"))"`. Below is the code I'm using with the specific path & GUIDs. I tried adjusting the sharepoint address, but the one listed is the one that points to the library. I also tried just the home address (Stopping at "TEP") and all the way to including "All Items.aspx". I'm sure I am missing something "simple", but just thought I'd try to ask here.

```
Dim objMyList As ListObject
Dim objWksheet As Worksheet 
Dim strSPServer As String


Const SERVER As String = "https://twdc.sharepoint.com/sites/WDPR-dclrecruiting/Test/TEP/Trip%20Event%20Planning%20Library"
Const LISTNAME As String = "{6B39FDF1-29AE-418C-9D99-92293FED5C81}"
Const VIEWNAME As String = "{CCFD1C7F-74CA-4921-A599-628C800C818A}"

strSPServer = "http://" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin"

Set objWksheet = Worksheets.Add

Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _
    Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), False, xlYes, Range("A1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works in my local

```
Sub ExportList()
    Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
    Dim strSPServer As String
    Const SERVER As String = "sp/sites/team"
    Const LISTNAME As String = "{3e47ff9c-9aab-4a40-9d6a-c47e9b793484}" 'From source code
    Const VIEWNAME As String = "{67709eda-c975-4669-85e5-d95e263dadc6}" 'From source code

   ' The SharePoint server URL pointing to the SharePoint list to import into Excel.
    strSPServer = "http://" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin"
    Set objWksheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Add a list range to the newly created worksheet
    ' and populated it with the data from the SharePoint list.
    Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), True, , Range("A1"))
    Set objMyList = Nothing
    Set objWksheet = Nothing
End Sub
```